# Javascript regex for mysql time stamp format not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to recognize if a string has the proper mysql DB time stamp format in javascript. I wrote this regexp:

```
var regex = /([0..9]{4})-([0..9]{2})-([0..9]{2}) ([0..9]{2}):([0..9]{2}):([0..9]{2})/;
```

However when used with the string

```
var s = "2014-09-08 08:02:17";
if (regex.test){
   console.log("OK");
}
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: replace `..` with `-`..

Comment: Thank you. Please post it as answer so I can mark it right. Worst part about it is that I looked it up and did not see the difference.

Comment: @aarelovich try [this link](http://regexr.com) to test your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add anchors and replace `..` with `-`. Because `-` inside a character class (not at the first or last) should act like a range quantifier.

```
var regex = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$/;
```

And anchors, yes it's must. Otherwise your regex should match this `54632014-09-08 08:02:173563` . Anchors will do an exact match,  you may replace anchors with `\b` if you don't want to do an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

The regex for this date format is : `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})`

Here a JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2vh23Lmt/

```js
    var string = "2014-09-08 08:02:17";
    var re = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/g;
    if (re.test(string)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: `([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2} (?:[\d]{2}:){2}[\d]{2})` will complete it faster, as it takes less steps (7 according to my regex tester). It all depends on whether the op is doing 1 or many. [here](https://regex101.com/r/yO6pK2/1)

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 errors in your approach:

- a) incorrect character class `[0..9]`(should be `[0-9]`);
- b) tested string is not specified in `regex.test` function call

---

```
 var regex = /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g;
 var s = "2014-09-08 08:02:17";
 if (regex.test(s)){
    console.log("OK");
 }
```